# Git commit is not working

Tags: git

Hoi everybody,

When i try to commit a file it gives me the following warning:

`Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit 
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)`

Comment: Use git push to publish your local commits. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You made a commit. Now, you have to push it on a remote server.

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

Your commit worked. Therefore you now have a commit more localy than on your remote repository. If you push your changes both will be sync'ed again.